# How to write a sentence with "challenge" and "himself"? - "He always challenged himself if ..."

Tags: idiomatic-language

Consider the sentence I created:

> He always challenged himself if the war is worth the price he pays.

Is that ***challenged himself if*** part an idiomatic and well-written English?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: To "challenge himself **if**" is not idiomatic.  Reflexive verb **challenge** is not complemented by an *if*-clause, as **ask** is. It can be complemented by an infinitival clause: to challenge oneself to {VERB} ....

Comment: _He always asks himself if the war is worth the price he pays._
_He always wonders if the war is worth the price he pays._ _He always challenges himself to come up with a good reason for the war_

Answer (score 1):

I would say your example sentence is not idiomatic in that **he** would not be challenging **himself**, but "**the war**", whatever it might be, is challenging *(to)* him.

One might usually express this as

> He always ***rose to the occasion*** if the fight was worth it.
>   He ***met*** the challenge, if it was worth it.

Using "**war**" might be a bit over the top, unless there is additional context and implicit is that a person would not fight if it was not "*worth it*" (the price to pay).

Answer (score 0):

I notice two issues with this sentence:

- As Peter's answer explains, the context of "war" and "price" indicates an external challenge, so it isn't compatible with the phrase "challenged himself".  See Peter's answer for other phrases for an external challenge.  In contrast,
  [Google shows that](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22challenged%20himself%22) the phrase "challenged himself" is widely used with personal challenges, like:

  > He challenged himself to climb Mt. Everest
- The coordination of tenses is incorrect between "challenged...is...pays" (past...present...present).  There are several ways to resolve this, such as past...past...past:

  > He always met the challenge, if the fight was worth the price he paid.

  or perhaps [habitual past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_modal_verbs#Will_and_would)...past...[future-in-the-past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Future-in-the-past):

  > He would always meet the challenge, if the fight was worth the price he would pay.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Two points. First: the challenge here is the thoughts in his mind, the questions he asks himself, or reviweing things happend to him, pondering and .... . Second: I used the present tense to imply that that also holds in the time of speaking or it continues to now.